# dockerd with userland-proxy set to false

Tags: docker, docker-proxy

Configured docker daemon with --iptables=true and --userland-proxy=false.

With that no more docker-proxy processes.

But, containers on the host can't talk with each other through the host IP and forwarded port on host.

This seems to be expected. But is there anyway to enable container to container communication through host forwarded ports (without getting into iptables modification each and everytime a new container is brought up).

```
[root@AppServer ~]# docker version
Client:
 Version:      18.03.1-ol
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.4
 Git commit:   0d51d18
 Built:        Wed Aug 22 21:59:42 2018
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.1-ol
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.4
  Git commit:   0d51d18
  Built:        Wed Aug 22 22:03:05 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
[root@AppServer ~]#
```

Comment: Why not just have containers communicate with eachother directly? Put them on the same user-defined networks and you can use container *names* instead of ip addresses.

Comment: Pre-determining container names is not feasible. But, I do know forwarding ports on the host. So, usecase is to communicate b/w containers through the HOST.